# removing white space in promoted links

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, branding

hi I want to remove white spaces in promoted links  and I used below code but it doesnot work and I use a script editor for this code in my page what should I do

.ms-webpartPage-root {

border-spacing: 0px !important;

}

.ms-webpartzone-cell {

margin: 0px !important;

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the DOM elements on the final page with the Developer Tools in IE or Chrome (F12) and work out which style gets actually applied to the element in question. Then add custom CSS via your established channel that overrides that CSS style.

Comment: And to override you probably need CSS with Higher [Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) instead of an !important rule

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman In most cases I've encountered, the `!important` would do the trick for the same class if the custom CSS is loaded last in the page. Sometimes that is easier than even trying to pronounce `specificity`, never mind understanding how it works. :)

Comment: The (only) problem with ``!important`` is: No other styles can be applied anymore, so if Behnoush on another page wants another margin.. he can't change it with CSS when its glued with !important. Yes Specificity takes time to understand (maybe an hour with [this explanation](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/): , after Selectors it is one of the most powerfull CSS features

Comment: That makes sense! I still can't pronounce `specificity` :)

Comment: I have named my daughter Specificity...

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - Makes me glad I have only boys. :-)))

Comment: Bill? Steve? Satya?